# Write to alpha channel of framebuffer color buffer

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es-2.0

The GLES 2.0 spec says that RGBA4444 is a valid color type for a frame buffer. How can data be written to the alpha channel when rendering to texture? Can it be done from a fragment shader? Can it be done without any extensions that are not available on all iOS and Android devices that support ES 2.0?

This would be useful for depth of field effects, where a size for the circle of confusion could be encoded into each pixel in the alpha channel.

It would also be preferable to not require a special fragment shader to write to the alpha channel. Otherwise, all the shaders would have to be swapped out when rendering the scene to the frame buffer used for blur calculations vs. rendering directly to the main buffer.

Answer (score 0):

performance wise using RGBA4444 could potentially bring some benefits. In the end the bit resolution for each color + alpha is half of the 8888 counter part.

As far as I know, your textures need to be converted in some way to reflect the format.

If not strictly required I guess that it is a rather cumbersome change in the approach you would normally follow in an 8888 format.

Another task would be to convert the formats of the textures before you actually use it but it is a rather costly process in the end.

Here there is a very good discussion about it:

[Creating and loading .pngs in RGBA4444 RGBA5551 for openGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008842/creating-and-loading-pngs-in-rgba4444-rgba5551-for-opengl)

I hope to have helped in some way.

Maurizio

Comment: I'm talking about rendering to texture. Not all devices support RGBA8888 for a color-writable frame buffer because it's not in the ES 2.0 specification. But that's beside the point. I'm asking how to write to the alpha channel of a color buffer when rendering to texture.

Comment: it's not half the bit resolution it's a sixteenth. Four bits is 0-15 for each component and eight bits is 0-255 for each component, sixteen times greater resolution.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can alter alpha channel in fragment shader. You don't need any specific extensions to access alpha channel in fragment shader. Data can be written as easy as this:

```
gl_FragColor.a = your_float_value; // set alpha separately
gl_FragColor = your_vec4_value; // alpha is a part of vec4 value (a or w component)
```

You need to alter shaders to calculate appropriate alpha value and set alpha channel.

Comment: I'm talking about writing to a frame buffer. This is just the alpha color from the fragment shader, which is used in whatever blendfunc you set up. What I want to know is how to write to the alpha channel of a texture when rendering to a texture (frame buffer color buffer).

Comment: Blending works the same way whether you are drawing into an FBO or the default framebuffer. The default blend function will multiply  the fragment's color by **1.0** and then write it to the color buffer. Technically it also multiplies the existing color in the color buffer by **0.0** and adds that, but I don't need to explain why multiplying by **0.0** is worthy of ignoring. Nevertheless, the pixel format of your default framebuffer is completely irrelevant here - you need a ***texture image*** that stores an alpha channel (e.g. `GL_RGBA8`).